Using .refreshable() and .searchable() in the same SwiftUI view
GIF Reproducing the error
Can someone please enlighten me on why the view stutters whenever I pull down to refresh? This behavior occurs when .refreshable() and .searchable() are in the same view. If I remove .searchable(), the refresh animation behaves normally. This problem haunts me in every project, and this is just simple SwiftUI code. What am I doing wrong? What is the issue here?
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    let listings: [String] = ["Hello world", "Hello StackOverflow"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Group {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(listings, id: \.self) { item in
                            Text(item)
                        }
                    }
                    .refreshable {}
                    .navigationTitle("Listings")
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $text)
        .task {}
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}


probably because the drag down gesture both shows the search box and the refresh spinner, maybe you could make the search box always visible.

It turns out that .navigationTitle is clashing with .searchable. Attaching the modifier  .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) works as a temporary solution by moving the title out of the way, but this is not right.
